# html 5 canvas not resizing after javascript resize

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I have the following html and css for a Tetris game I am making:

**html**

```
<div id = "TetrisHolder">
  <canvas id = "TetrisCanvas" style = "width:400px; height:500px"></canvas>
</div>
```

**css**

```
div#TetrisHolder {
  display: table;
  margin:auto;
  background: black;
  border: solid black 3px;
}

canvas#TetrisCanvas {
  background: url(Resources/bg.png) no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover ;
}
```

When I attempt to resize it with the following javascript, nothing happens. I have seen most other StackOverflow questions about resizing DOM elements answered this way, however it does not work for me. what am I missing?

note: I am aware that I will need to redraw what is on the canvas but all I want right now is to resize it.

**js**

```
function resize() {
  canvas = document.getElementById("TetrisCanvas");
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  canvas.width = window.innerWidth*0.6;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight*0.6;
}
```

Comment: Remove the inline CSS from your HTML markup

Comment: ps : I'm talking about `style = "width:400px; height:500px">` in `<canvas id = "TetrisCanvas" style = "width:400px; height:500px"></canvas>`. pps I voted to close as typo

Comment: that was actually what i was looking for, strange, because i thought i had tried that. But Thanks!